# Broadcasting only with specific dimensions of ndarray in python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, simd, array-broadcasting

Consider a `TxFxM` ndarray. I wish to multiply it with its conjugate, only for the `M` dimension while keeping the other dimensions the same as presented in the following code:

```
import numpy as np

T=2
F=3
M=4

x=np.random.rand(T,F,M)

result=np.zeros((T,F,M,M))

for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            result[i,j,:,:]=np.matmul(np.expand_dims(x[i,j,:],axis=1),np.expand_dims(x[i,j,:],axis=0).conj())
```

If I simply use broadcasting as in `np.matmul(x,x.conj().T)`, The broadcast operation will continue to higher levels of dimensions and keep multiplying. On the other hand, my implementation is very slow due to two loops and very unpythonic to my understanding.

Is there a way to implement this S.T. it will run faster?

P.S.

- My dimensions are obviously larger `T=3000,F=1024,M=4`, And this operation repeats itself, hence my requirement for a fast implementation.
- I plan to average this over dimension `T`, so if there is a faster total implementation I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0):

The array you need can be computed with broadcasting if you inject singleton dimensions in two different places for `x` and `x.conj()`. If `x` has shape `(T,F,M)` then arrays of shape `(T,F,M,1)` and `(T,F,1,M)` will broadcast to `(T,F,M,M)` just the way you want it. Here's your example with complex data to make sure we're not missing something:

```
import numpy as np 

T,F,M = 2,3,4 

x = np.random.rand(T,F,M) + np.random.rand(T,F,M)*1j 

result = np.zeros((T,F,M,M), dtype=complex) 

# loop
for i in range(x.shape[0]): 
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        result[i,j,:,:] = np.matmul(np.expand_dims(x[i,j,:],axis=1),
                                    np.expand_dims(x[i,j,:],axis=0).conj())

# broadcasting
result2 = x[..., None] * x[..., None, :].conj()

# proof
print(np.array_equal(result, result2))  # True
```

Since you mentioned that you want to take a mean along the `T`-sized dimension, we have to consider whether it's worth putting this dimension last, so that the mean makes use of as contiguous blocks of memory as possible. This means the following options:

```
def summed_original(x): 
    """Assume x.shape == (T, F, M), return summed array of shape (F, M, M)""" 
    return (x[..., None] * x[..., None, :].conj()).mean(0) 

def summed_transposed(x): 
    """Assume x.shape == (F, M, T), return summed array of shape (F, M, M)""" 
    return (x[..., None, :] * x[:, None, ...].conj()).mean(-1) 

x_transposed = x.transpose(1, 2, 0).copy()  # ensure contiguous copy 
print(np.allclose(summed_original(x), summed_transposed(x_transposed)))  # True
```

As you can see these two functions compute the same thing, but they assume the input to have different memory order. The reason why this is important is because it might prove faster to have your original array in a different memory layout (at the cost of transposing and copying it once at the start, if need be).

So let's time them using IPython's `%timeit` magic and your real sizes:

```
T,F,M = 3000,1024,4 
x = np.random.rand(T, F, M) + np.random.rand(T, F, M)*1j 
x_transposed = x.transpose(1, 2, 0).copy() 
print(np.allclose(summed_original(x), summed_transposed(x_transposed)))  # True

%timeit summed_original(x)
# 500 ms ± 16.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit summed_transposed(x_transposed)
# 352 ms ± 2.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see, for your specific sizes and types it seems well worth rearranging the dimensions of your array so that the `T` dimension corresponds to contiguous blocks of memory, aiding caching in the CPU. You can either do this with a `.transpose(...).copy()` call at the start, or even better you might construct your array such in the first place, making the code optimal.